# Oracle Apex 4.2 restful URL with GlassFish

Tags: glassfish-3, oracle-apex

Is there any differences between Restful URL web services if you use embedded HTTP or with Glassfish? the problem i am facing right now, i couldn't access sample Restful web service (get employee) from url :

```
http://localhot:port/apex/hr/employees
```

i am using glassfish.

Please kindly help me solved this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it looks like the problem is on my listenerAdmin configuration, now its working fine.